# Font settings in css

Tags: css

I have two spans as

```
 <span class="class-1">Text1</span>
 <span class="class-1">Text2</span>
```

And `.class-1` has the styles

```
.class-1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

Now I need to remove the `font-weight: bold` from the `.Text-2`, can this be done without creating another css class?

Comment: font-bold: true is invalid css rules

Comment: `class-1` is missing a leading `.`. And what color is `read`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YrNQz/)

```
 <span class="class-1">Text1</span>
 <span class="class-1">Text2</span>
```

And class-1 has the styles

```
.class-1 {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: red;
    }


.class-1 + .class-1{/*this will be applied on the secound span*/
      font-weight: normal;
      color:green;
    }
```

this alternative:

```
.class-1 {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: red;
    }


.class-1:last-child{/*this will be applied on the secound span*/
      font-weight: normal;
      color:green;
    }
/*or this*/
.class-1:nth-child(2){
      font-weight: normal;
      color:green;
    }
```

**inline css**

```
<span class="class-1" style="font-weight: bold;color: red;">Text1</span>
<span class="class-1" style="font-weight: normal;color:green;">Text2</span>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YrNQz/1/)

and if you have something in between

**HTML:**

```
<span class="class-1">Text1</span>
<p>Hello do you have time to talk about  Css?</p>
<span class="class-1">Text2</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.class-1 {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: red;
    }

.class-1:nth-of-type(2) { 
    font-weight: normal;
    color: green; 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YrNQz/2/)

Comment: Should be aware that all these selectors fall under http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code looks roughly something like this

```
<style>
.class-1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
</style>
<span class="class-1">Text 1</span>
<span class="class-1">Text 2</span>
```

You could add the style attribute to Text 2's span if you absolutely cannot create a class.  Altered it looks like below.

```
<span class="class-1" style="font-weight: normal;">Text 2</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, any way to exclude the inline style as this will be rejected saying not a good practice

Comment: I commented in the other thread but n-th child selectors fall under http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 so it depends on what browsers you need to support.